# Image is not loading in blade view

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, laravel

I am trying to fetch the image from the path /public/uploads/advertisements and bind it in `<img>` tag in my view

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/advertisements/20150703111131.jpg') }}"   style="max-height: 250px; max-width: 250px;">
```

but it wont show when i inspect it with firebug it gives me something like this

```
<img class="vikkipgrsmacxycazywj" style="max-height: 250px; max-width: 250px;" src="http://example.com/uploads/advertisements/20150703111131.jpg">
```

The class `"vikkipgrsmacxycazywj"` gets added automatically, and the whole `<img>` tag gets hidden.

The image is present at the location and the URL is valid.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: This most certainly has nothing to do with laravel. Are you using some javascript plugin that could add such a class?

Comment: @lukasgeiter thank you for your suggestion but i have tried this code on an empty view with no js no css but still no luck..

Comment: Maybe a browser plugin?

Comment: `{!! asset('uploads/20150703111131.jpg') !!}`

Comment: i second @lukasgeiter opinion, it's some browser plugin that adds this class to your image, maybe even malicious, did you try opening in different browser?

Comment: guys it was a browser plugin afteall, thank you @rozklad and lukasgeiter for your sugesstions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had faced similar issue and I scratched my head for whole day, then I realized that last evening I had installed ad blocker extension.

As you have path as

> uploads/advertisements/20150703111131.jpg

Due to 'advertisements' in path, this image is blocked. Try disabling your add-ons.